# How to store value in a For loop

Tags: assignment

I am using two `For` loops. When the inner loop finishes, I don't want to print but I want to store the result from the inner loop in some variable so that I can call that variable in the future. That result will come in the form of a list.

For example, in the 1st iteration,it is returning some value, e.g. {2,4}.
        in the 2nd iteration,it is returning {3,4}.

But I don't want to print them every time. I want some variable to store {{2,4},{3,4}}.
How to do that?

Here I am retrieving all the data except Null.

```
tab={{{"option1", "option3", "option4", "optio", "Null", 
        "Null"}, {"option2", "option5", "option6", "option7", "Null", "Null"}, 
         {"option", "op", "Null", "Null", "Null", "Null"}}};

For[j = 1, j <= Length[tab[[1]]], j++,
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[Rest[tab[[1, j]]]], i++,

If[TrueQ[(Rest[tab[[1, j]]][[i]]) == "Null"], count++, count = 0]]
 Print[
Table[Rest[tab[[1, j]]][[i]], {i,1, (Length[Rest[tab[[1, j]]]] - count), 1}]] ]
```

Comment: Please post a code sample

Comment: Not only should you post a code sample, but since there is a high probability that a method better than `For` loops exists for your problem please also explain the context of the code.

Comment: Usually, one could use `AppendTo[]` or the combination of `Sow[]`/`Reap[]`, but without something more concrete, we can't be more helpful.

Comment: I have posted my code sample.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, but I am not clear with the concepts of  &,@,#.So tried with For loop. Is there any other way or some modification to what I tried by For loop

Comment: I updated my answer with a direct modification of the `For` loop, but I highly recommend learning about `&`, `@`, `#`, etc.!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks... ok I will try to learn all these functions too.

Comment: I promise it will be worth your time.  Thanks for adding the code as requested to your question; that earned my +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In light of your update, is this all you're trying to do?

```
Cases[#, Except@"Null"] & /@ tab[[1, All, 2 ;;]]
```

> {{"option3", "option4", "optio"}, {"option5", "option6", 
>     "option7"}, {"op"}}

Specific references to understand this code for your convenience:
[Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html), [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html), [Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html), [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html), [Cases](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html), [Except](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Except.html)

---

If for some reason you feel you *must* use `For` loops, you can substitute [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) for `Print` as follows:

```
Reap[
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[tab[[1]]], j++,
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[Rest[tab[[1, j]]]], i++,
    If[TrueQ[(Rest[tab[[1, j]]][[i]]) == "Null"], count++, count = 0]
   ];
   Sow @ Table[
     Rest[tab[[1, j]]][[i]], {i, 
      1, (Length[Rest[tab[[1, j]]]] - count), 1}]
  ]
][[2, 1]]
```

> {{"option3", "option4", "optio"}, {"option5", "option6", 
>     "option7"}, {"op"}}

Comment: `DeleteCases[#, "Null"]` seems clearer and avoids her learning `Except` yet, hehe

Answer (score 3):

A version using `Select`, `Map` ( shortform  `/@` ) and lambda functions ( `#` and `&` ).

```
Select[Rest@#, # =!= "Null" &] & /@ First@tab
```

> {{"option3", "option4", "optio"}, {"option5", "option6", 
>     "option7"}, {"op"}}

I wasn't sure if `tab` was intended to have an apparently redundant layer of nesting, as in {**{**{...},{...},{..}**}**}, if it wasn't you can drop the extra braces and remove `First` from the code.

Did you also want to ignore the first element of each sublist of `tab` as per Mr Wizards answer? If not, then you can drop `Rest` from the code given.