# How do I store values in a for loop into an array and then plot that array?

Tags: list-manipulation

What my title said and I want to plot the values of the array.  still new to mathematica and programming so its hard to formulate my question just right

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. You should be able to piece something together with the help of the documentation.

Comment: `For[]` and loops in general are usually a bad idea in Mathematica. See for example: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/193

Comment: This question has been asked many times before.  I picked one and closed this question ad a duplicate of it.  (See the link in the header added to your question.)  See also: [(4496)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4496/121) and 
[(9455)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9455/121).  Finally, please read this for some examples of how you can improve your approach: [(7924)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121)

Answer (score 4):

This is how you should **NOT** do it in Mathematica:

```
list = {};
f[x_] := x^4
For[i = 1, i < 100, i++, AppendTo[list, f[i]]];
ListLinePlot@list
```

And this is one of the many possible better ways:

```
ListLinePlot@ f @ Range@100
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]